# Accidentally deleted Ubuntu volume from Windows?

Tags: grub2, 16.04

I had Ubuntu dual booted with UEFI  in my disk and I accidentally deleted that partition. I am still in Windows and haven't shut it down.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use EasyBCD: (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/)

Under BCD backup/repair, go to BCD management option, and select Re-create/repair boot files and click perform action.

This will wipe GRUB and doing this you cannot go to Ubuntu anymore.

OPTION 2 (thx @NathanOsman): LIVECD/or USB

1. You have to sign the waviers and leave Windows. Make sure you have a liveCD!
2. Boot from it and select "Try ubuntu without installing."
3. Now there are 2 steps

STEP 1: if you have removed linux-swap partition

1. Open Gparted: (if you dont have it `sudo apt-get install gparted`)
2. Make a new linux-swap (size you say? please make it the same as your RAM size ex. I have 8 gb of ram (yes I am a ram hog) and the swap size is 8gb!

STEP 2: Boot Repair
(docs are here, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)
Open a freshly baked Terminal session and put this down.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

(one line before the other)

Now the thingy should appear and click RECOMMENDED REPAIR.

STEP 3: REINSTALL

If else fails: try reinstalling Ubuntu. Easy as pie.

Comment: Grub can be repaired using a LiveCD.

Comment: I have files under ubuntu , would those be available ?

Comment: If you have deleted ubuntu then your files has been already wiped